# X was the case, so/but/since/because Y happened

Tags: conjunctions

The car dashed the tree. It was going at over 100mph.

> A) The blue car was going 100mph, so it dashed the tree.
>  
>   B) The blue car was going at over 100mph, but it dashed the tree.
>  
>   C) The blue car was going at over 100mph, since it dashed the tree.
>  
>   D) The blue car was going at over 100mph because it dashed the tree.