# The solution of so/but/since and because?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, conjunctions, expression-choice

[image: what do you think about these options, i chose A, but you]

What do you think about the options of this case, i hav chosen the A", it's a little tricky?

Comment: What do you think? please include your findings or ideas.

Comment: Dictionaries probably won't convey this, but nowadays ***to dash*** isn't used so often in the original sense of *strike violently*. We now tend to use ***smash, crash*** (informally, ***bash***) for that sense, reserving figurative ***dash*** for *move hurriedly*.

Comment: "A" is the correct one. however, like @FumbleFingers said, try not to use "dash."

Comment: This is a question of my high school test, and i wrote this here to make sure which is the correct option!

Comment: As @Eilia wrote, please include your own findings, and why they do not adequately answer the question for you. Also, **please give questions usable titles**. “Choose the correct answer” says absolutely nothing about your question. Also please don’t choose random, irrelevant tags—this has nothing to do with grammatical gender, for example; it’s about _conjunctions_.

Comment: Honestly, I think the best way to combine those sentences would be "the blue car was going 100 mph _until_ it dashed against a tree," but none of those are very good answers.

Comment: Maybe!! But this is one kind of options

Comment: Hang on. Are you, _FERIDE 1998_, the same person who asked the same question an hour or so ago, and whose name was _Feride_? If so, what was wrong with the replies you got then?

Comment: Yep, i was that one who posted the last question about this case! The reason why i posted the pic is cause I've made a mistake in writing the question and i couldn't change so i found the pic after searchin' about this!

Comment: You should see an edit button that you can click.

Comment: I'll agree with @SomethingDark. The ***best*** way to join these sentences would be with *when* or *until*. None of these are very good answers, but B are is probably the best choice.

Comment: Hang on. I gave the answer as B in your original question and all I got was criticism in the form of downvotes. I don't mind if no-one liked my answer but it turns out it was the answer you accepted here, so not only does someone else benefit from the arguments in the original thread but I get minus rep for giving the accepted answer. You should have learnt how to properly edit your first question and deal with it there.

Comment: I didn't do that for any reason! I apologise for that i posted before, all i want from one of u is to share opinions of this case! Sorry and thank you @MarvMills

Comment: @MarvMills - for what it's worth, I came to my answer without knowing that this question had been asked before. I've also upvoted your answer because it's correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [X was the case, so/but/since/because Y happened](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251358/x-was-the-case-so-but-since-because-y-happened)

Comment: Why u comment all the time u @SomethingDark, comment once and finish.. not several time worth nthg! Bb

Comment: @Feride - because that's how this website works. I _strongly_ suggest you lurk more to get a feel for how users interact with each other.

Comment: Okey bye , u gorgeoussss worker of this site, cause u can't blame nthg! @SomethingDark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, none of those choices are particularly good, but some are better than others. This answer is more along the lines of general multiple-choice strategy than an explanation of grammar, but I'll try to explain why the best choice is B.

Generally, cars tend to stop moving when they hit trees, and so the best way to combine the two sentences would either be to say that the car was going 100 MPH *when* it hit the tree, or that the car was going 100 MPH *until* it hit the tree.

**C** and **D** mean the same thing (the car was propelled to a speed of over 100 mph as a result of hitting the tree), so they're obviously both wrong.

**A** *could* be correct in the context of there being some sort of barrier that would have prevented objects moving slower than 100 mph from hitting the tree - "the blue car was going fast enough to break through the barrier, and therefore it hit the tree."

**B**, while poorly written, is most likely the correct answer, as it could be read as "the blue car *was* going at over 100 mph... but then it hit a tree." Since this answer requires fewer assumptions than answer **A**, it is a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

**None of the answers is correct.** "The car dashed the tree" is not correct English, and no variations on it are going to be correct.

When used with an object, to "dash" something means to strike with it. So "I dashed the glass on the floor". If "the car dashed the tree", it means the car picked up the tree and hit something with it. That is obviously not what is meant.

(There are other meanings of dash, such as to go fast, or to draw a line with dashes, but none of them are applicable here. Ancient writers also used 'dashed' in this way, but if you are learning to speak modern English I really don't recommend it - most people you speak to will assume you are incorrect in using 'dashed' this way)

Some sentences that might be correct, and mean the car struck the tree:

- The car dashed against the tree
- The car dashed into the tree

However 'dashed' is not the best word to use in this case. Most English speakers would use 'crashed'.

To deal with the prepositions, which is what your question is about, either "so"  or "but" would be applicable. "So" means that the 100mph speed was the reason for it striking the tree; "but" means that striking the tree caused it to stop going at 100mph. 'Since' and 'because' both would mean that crashing into the tree was the reason it was going 100mph, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: _Dash_ in this sense is highly archaic, but I wouldn’t say it’s “not correct” as such. It has been used in this way for a long time, though it’s exceedingly rare nowadays. The OED has this very similar quote from Gibbon’s _A History of the Rise and Fall of the Roman Empire_: “The oars of Theodosius dashed the waves of the Hyperborean ocean.”

Comment: Given the age of that usage, and the rather different kind of striking involve with oars on an ocean and a car on a tree, I'm going to stick with "incorrect" for practical purposes.

Comment: For some reason, I took "dashed against" to mean "ricocheted off of."

Answer (score 1):

**There is no answer given that is surely correct.** Answers A or B in some cases might be, but we do not know.

Even if you would use "dash into" and left out "blue" in the answers there is no expression that is known to be correct.

Definitely correct only a combination with **and** or **before** would be, because

`The car dashed the tree. It was going at over 100mph.`

only gives little information:

- Car dashed tree
- Car was faster than 100mph some time before the crash (directly or before it left the street or if it even was on one is not known)

`The car was going at over 100mph and dashed into the tree.`

`The car was going at over 100mph before it dashed into the tree.`

A closer look why all answer can be or must be wrong.

`A) The (blue) car was going 100mph, so it dashed 'into' the tree.`

So? Is the dash a result of going 100mph? Would it not have crashed into it with lesser speed? Would it have been possible to miss the tree even with 100mph?

`B) The (blue) car was going at over 100mph, but it dashed 'into' the tree.`

Why but? What did the crash prevent the car from? Reaching the finish line? Getting over 110mph?

`C) The (blue) car was going at over 100mph, since it dashed 'into' the tree.`

Since? It definitely did not go at over 100mph as a result of the dash.

`D) The (blue) car was going at over 100mph because it dashed 'into' the tree.`

Because? Same as answer C.

Answer (score 0):

B is the correct answer since the others make the car's speed conditional on crashing into the tree, or the crash dependent on the speed. In others words they all say that the car's speed was 100mph *because* it crashed into the tree or it crashed *because* it was going 100mph

Since cars can go 100mph *without* crashing into trees and can crash without going 100mph, B is the correct answer since neither the speed nor the crash are co-dependent in this question.

Consider:

> A) The aardvark was 10 years old, so it died.
>
> B) The aardvark was over 10 years old, but it died.
>
> C) The aardvark was over 10 years old, since it died.
>
> D) The aardvark was over 10 years old, because it died.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense. B makes it sound like going 100 mph is supposed to make it less likely for a car to crash into trees, which is obviously not true. It is not correct to state unequivocally that the speed and the crash are not codependent; the most likely reading is that the car crashed into the tree because it was going 100 mph, which means the driver was unable to swerve to avoid the tree in time. If he’d only been going 50 mph, he might have been able to avoid the crash.

Comment: Given the only context we have is the question, there is nothing there to support that the speed caused the crash or the crash caused the speed. Therefore they are merely linked sentences and the only answer that supports that is B.

Comment: No, B does not support that either. **None** of the options support them being merely linked sentences; only _and_ would do that, and that’s not an option. _But_ makes no sense, just like it makes no sense to say, “He weighs 160 lb., but he lives in a house”. _But_ is used to indicate a **contrast** between the sentences it links, and there is no contrast between going 100 mph and hitting a tree; there is, in fact, a correlation, albeit a very weak one.

Comment: The red car was only going 60mph and it won whereas the blue car was going 100mph but crashed into a tree.

Comment: Yes—and that does exactly what I did in the first comment: it adds additional context not available in the question to make the option make sense. You could do that with all four options. The only option that has a higher-than-average level of correlation _with no further context_ is A, since high speeds **are** (vaguely) correlated with head-on crashes.

Comment: I take your point. I don't like A because of the strong causal relationship. It states that the crash occurred because of a speed of 100mph, not 99 or 101, but 100mph. That is not the case- the speed doesn't cause the crash, it is the inability of this driver to handle the speed that causes the crash otherwise no speedo would ever need to go higher than 99 since 100 would always cause a crash. B is still the only one that seems to make sense, if not due to my earlier statement then because it describes a sequence of events and the crash reduced the speed (emphasis on 'was' in statement)

Comment: You are right @ Marv Mills, B could be correct, as A could also. As Janus said, given more information, we could be able to judge the answers. Actually we have to little information to do so.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Answer A is **false** because this option say that the car was going 100 mph, but in the sentence they say that the car was going **at over** 100 mph.

Coordinating conjunctions are used to join words, phrases, and clauses that are balanced as logical equals.

the purpose of the question was to join sentences, and to do so we can use the seven coordinating conjunctions:

> and 
>   but
>   or 
>   nor
>   for
>   so 
>   yet

The option that has **because** is false. That left us with the option that has the conjuction **So**.

the conclusion is that the correct answer is:

> The car was going at over 100 mph but it dashed against the tree.